# Add index signature to union of generic type element

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm trying to add an index signature to a union of an element of a generic type and another type. Here is a basic example:

```js
function foo<T extends any[]>() {
  const a = {} as ({} | T[number]) & { [key: string]: any };
  const b = a['bar'];
}
```

Here, the second line inside the function throws the following error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"bar"' can't be used to index type '{ [key: string]: any; } | (T[number] & { [key: string]: any; })'.
> Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: any; } | (T[number] & { [key: string]: any; })'.

What is interesting is that if I remove one element of the union type or replace the second element with anything that's not an element signature of the generic type, it works (might be another pattern, which I haven't noticed).

Why does this specific case throw an error? Is there any other way to add an index signature to a union type that contains the element type of a generic type?

Comment: Does `function foo<T extends {}[]>()` work?